# Angular Cisco Duo intergration

Tags: node.js, angular, types, two-factor-authentication, duosecurity

I'm integrating Angular with Cisco Duo Web SDK. The example I found [here](https://github.com/abuzzi-cisco/angular-duo), that I'm following. From Cisco Duo, I get a secret ID, client ID, etc., but in the example, the user is using sig_request like this:

`sig_request: "TX|YWJXXXX...."`.

How do I get a sig_request like that instead of using the secret ID, client ID, etc. provided by Cisco Duo?